# How to fix Unity Hub's "could not be opened. Please check the logs." error

Tags: unity-game-engine

Whenever I create a new project, I can't seem to open it. It displays "My Project could not be opened. Please check the Logs". Whenever I try to open the Unity Editor directly (Unity 2020.3.30f1), an Application Error shows up.

Comment: I would probably start by doing what you are told: Check the logs ;)

Comment: @derHugo I did, but what do I do next? All there are are two .json files.

Comment: Well what do they say?

Comment: @derHugo Nothing else actually

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to Open a Remote project with Unity that was using PlasticSCM. My Default Location path was set to an existing Unity Project Folder, instead of the Github folder where my Source control projects are located.

In the UnityHub click the COG Wheel Icon next to the word Projects it should say "Preferences" when you hover over the COG Icon

Under the Projects tab change the Default Location folder.

**C:\Users\Your Username\Desktop\GitHub**

[Unity Hub Preferences Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbwus.png)